# A simple gradebook using structures

Tags: c++, c++11

I have this basic question about the efficient way to sort user-defined object. It can be done in many ways, but most of sorting algorithms at best cases is \$O(N)\$. I have come up with a fair approach to get \$O(N*log(size() + N))\$ by using `std::set`.

Is it a good choice in such a case?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <array>
#include <string>
#include <set>

struct Student
{
    std::string studentName;
    int midTermScore;
    char grade;

    friend bool operator<(Student const & a, Student const & b)
    {
        return a.midTermScore > b.midTermScore;
    }
};

template<typename C>
void display(const C& c)
{
    std::cout << std::left 
        << std::setw(10) << " Names"
        << std::setw(10) << "Exam" 
        << std::setw(10) << "Grade";

    std::cout << std::setfill('-') << std::setw(28) << '\n';

    for (const auto& i : c)
    {
        std::cout << "\n " << std::setfill(' ') << std::left
            << std::setw(10) << i.studentName
            << std::setw(11) << i.midTermScore
            << std::setw(2) << i.grade;
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::array<Student, 4> a
    {
        {
            { "me",     60, 'D'},
            {"matt",    88, 'B'},
            { "john",   93, 'A'},
            {"jesseca", 82, 'B'}

        }
    };

    display(a);

    std::set<Student> sorted;

    for (auto&& i : a)
    {
        sorted.insert(i); // O(N*log(size() + N))
    }

    std::cout << "\n\nafter sorting\n\n";

    display(sorted);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> i have given basic question about the efficient way to sort user-defined object

If you really care about performance, you should measure it. Experience shows that there are many subtle influences to performance, that make it hard to reliably predict it.

Instead of using a `std::set`, you could try sorting the array directly. It is less code, less memory and probably faster: `std::set` typically is implemented as a tree, and will allocate each node separately. When inserting elements not in order, the resulting nodes will most likely be scattered in memory. Iterating over such a set might be slower than iterating over a contiguous array or even over a set where the elements have been inserted in order. (Not that it would matter much with the small sample size in this program.)

`std::set` also provides guarantees that you don't need here: Stability of references/iterator, unique elements, "fast" insertion not just at the end, "fast" removal of elements.

Interestingly, because `std::set` guarantees unique elements, it might be **an incorrect choice in this context**. Students will not be inserted into the set if there's already a student with the same `midTermScore` when using your current definition of `operator<`. [Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/32f272cb531d38fe) You should either use a total order for the `std::set` or use a data structure that can contain multiple equivalent elements (equivalent with respect to the order) like `std::multiset`.

For example, instead of

> ```
> std::set<Student> sorted;
>
> for (auto&& i : a)
> {
>     sorted.insert(i); // O(N*log(size() + N))
> }
> ```

you could sort the original array:

```
std::sort(begin(a), end(a));
```

(that is `std::begin` and `std::end`, but I'm using ADL because I'm lazy)

---

> ```
> friend bool operator<(Student const & a, Student const & b)
> {
>     return a.midTermScore > b.midTermScore;
> }
> ```

I don't think it's a good idea to define an `operator<` for a type that does not provide a total order. We could try to introduce equality between two students by using `(a == b) <=> (!(a<b) && !(b<a))`  (I'm using `<=>` as *is equivalent to* here). But this notion of equality is strange, since we expect `(a == b) => (a.studentName == b.studentName)`.

After looking at the code again, I think it's even a worse idea to define the (canonical) `operator<` for a type be mean *greater than*.

Therefore, I'd rather use a function, function object type or lambda to introduce this order. For example, using `std::sort` from above:

```
auto const larger_midTermScore =
    [](Student const& a, Student const& b)
    { return a.midTermScore > b.midTermScore; }

std::sort(begin(a), end(a), larger_midTermScore);
```

I you want to use a `std::set`, you could impose that order on the set as follows:

```
class larger_midTermScore {
private:
    static auto tie_in_order(Student const& a)
    -> decltype(std::tie(a.midTermScore, a.grade, a.studentName)) {
        return std::tie(a.midTermScore, a.grade, a.studentName);
    }
public:
    bool operator() const (Student const& a, Student const& b) {
        return tie_in_order(a) < tie_in_order(b);
    }
};

// in the main function:
std::set<Student, larger_midTermScore> sorted(begin(a), end(a));
```

I'm being lazy again by using `std::tuple` to define a lexicographical comparison of the data members of `Student`. Include the `<tuple>` header.

---

> ```
> std::string studentName;
> int midTermScore;
> char grade;
> ```

The type `Student` might have invariants that you should protect.
For example, `'A' <= grade <= 'F'` etc. Also, it is unclear (because not documented nor enforced by encapsulation) if there is a maximum length for `studentName`. The `display` algorithm suggests there is one.

Comment: `Iterating over such a set might be slow.` => I would say `might by slower`. Unless the data set is huge you are not going to see a difference. It also depends an access patterns.

Comment: @CrappyExperienceBye With iterating, I mean sequential access. OP cares about performance, I agree it probably doesn't matter for this program. The main reason for not using `std::set` is less code here ;)

Comment: @CrappyExperienceBye I just noticed that `std::set` is probably wrong here anyway. It loses students with the same `midTermScore`. Using `std::multiset` to overcome this problem seems not a good idea to me either.

Comment: Or alter the `operator<` so that it compares more than the score so we don't make them equal if they have the same score.

Comment: @CrappyExperienceBye Yes, I should have pointed that out better.

Comment: i did profile it as you recommended. indeed, it's much faster by using `std::sort` than `std::set`. also when i used for-loop by `insert` member, it's 2X faster than `std::set<Student, larger_midTermScore> sorted(a.begin(), a.end())`

Answer (score 1):

The only think I would change is making a student know how to print itself (rather than display).

```
 static void displayHeader(std::ostream& str)
 {
   str  << std::left 
        << std::setw(10) << " Names"
        << std::setw(10) << "Exam" 
        << std::setw(10) << "Grade";
   str << std::setfill('-') << std::setw(28) << '\n';

 }
 friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& str, Student const& data)
 {
   str  << "\n " << std::setfill(' ') << std::left
        << std::setw(10) << i.studentName
        << std::setw(11) << i.midTermScore
        << std::setw(2) << i.grade;
   return str;
 }

 friend bool operator<(Student const & a, Student const & b)
 ....
```

Now display can be simplifies:

```
template<typename C>
void display(const C& c)
{
    typedef typename C::value_type  ValueType;
    ValueType::displayHeader(std::cout);

    for (const auto& i : c)
    {
        std::cout << i << "\n";
    }
}
```

You can improve on your insert into the sorted (no need for a loop).

```
std::set<Student> sorted(std::begin(a), std::end(a));
```

Comment: I agree with your intention of splitting up the `display` algorithm, but I disagree with increasing the coupling between the (seemingly) POD `Student` and the (essentially) adapters to features like stream IO (by adding member functions). Since none of those are templates in your approach, `displayHeader` could be a free function with internal linkage in some TU.